# how to get Specific Value from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4.2

[image: how to get these values]

I have to match this UID (userID) with the current userID for chat list kindly explain how to do

Comment: You marked two keys in the screenshot. What is the meaning of each of these, which one do you *know* in your app (vs the one you want to look up)? It would also really help if you show the code of what you already tried too.

Comment: Also, what does 'match' mean? If you know the path to the node you want, you can read it directly without a query. For example, if your Chatlist has child nodes that are user id's, `Chatlist/uid_0`, `Chatlist/uid_1` etc, you can just observe the node at `Chatlist/uid_0`